# R Get Sum of Column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe in R

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  questionID = c(1,1,3,4,5,5),
   userID = c(101, 101, 102, 101, 102,101),
   Value=c(10,20,30,40,50,10))
```

The basic idea is to have a column that indicates the sum of value for a user on questions they asked before (lower number questions).

I tried using this function (after trying the pipe of sum which just gave errors about non-numeric that everybody seems to face)

```
f2 <- function(x){
     Value_out <- filter(df1,questionID<x['questionID'] & userID == x['userID'] ) %>%
       select(Value) %>%
       summarize_if(is.numeric, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
}

out=mutate(df1,Expert=apply(df1, 1,f2))
```

While this works if you print it out, the Expert column is saved as a list of dataframes.  All I want is an int or numeric of the sum of Value.  Is there anyway to do this?  By the way, yes, I've looked all over for ways to do this, with most answers just summarizing the column in a manner that won't work for me.

Comment: note...if you use sum() instead, you will get this error " only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables "

Comment: it looks this may work with  colSums()

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. It's generally an anti-pattern to reassign a global variable inside a function like this; instead you should return a value, such as the vector you want to add to a data frame

Comment: If you add `Value_out <- as.numeric(Value_out)` to the end of the function it will become numeric instead of a column of data frames.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would avoid writing my own function altogether and use `data.table` on this one. You can do what you want in just a couple lines, and I wouldn't be surprised if there was a way to golf this down to fewer lines

Given your same data, we create a `data.table` object:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  questionID = c(1,1,3,4,5,5),
  userID = c(101, 101, 102, 101, 102,101),
  Value=c(10,20,30,40,50,10))
```

Next, we `shift` our values by 1 (lag) within each `userID`:

```
dt[, lastVal := shift(Value, n = 1, fill = 0), by = .(userID)]
```

And finally, we `cumsum` those by `userID`, and replace those with multiple `Value`s with the same `userID` x `questionID` with the min `Expert`, which should be 0 because we used `fill = 0` in `shift` above before we `cumsum`:

```
dt[, 
   Expert := cumsum(lastVal),
   by = .(userID)][,
                   Expert := min(Expert),
                   by = .(userID, questionID)]
```

So, putting that all together, we have:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  questionID = c(1,1,3,4,5,5),
  userID = c(101, 101, 102, 101, 102,101),
  Value=c(10,20,30,40,50,10))
dt[, lastVal := shift(Value, n = 1, fill = 0), by = .(userID)]
dt[, 
   Expert := cumsum(lastVal),
   by = .(userID)][,
                   Expert := min(Expert),
                   by = .(userID, questionID)]

dt

   questionID userID Value lastVal Expert
1:          1    101    10       0      0
2:          1    101    20      10      0
3:          3    102    30       0      0
4:          4    101    40      20     30
5:          5    102    50      30     30
6:          5    101    10      40     70
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `purrr::map_dbl` one approach would be to `group_by` `userID` and `sum` `Value` for each `questionID` which is less than current value.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(userID) %>%
  mutate(Expert = purrr::map_dbl(questionID, ~sum(Value[questionID < .x])))

#  questionID userID Value Expert
#       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1          1    101    10      0
#2          1    101    20      0
#3          3    102    30      0
#4          4    101    40     30
#5          5    102    50     30
#6          5    101    10     70
```